# Binary Tree sum of odd nodes

Tags: java

I wanted to know the sum of all odd nodes and was programming it in a resursive way.
But i cant make it work so maybe you guys can help me...

This is my BinNode Class

```
package com.company;

public class BinNode {
  public int element;
  public BinNode left, right;


public BinNode(int e, BinNode l, BinNode r) {
    element = e;
    left = l;
    right = r;
}

public BinNode(int e) {
    element = e;
    left = null;
    right = null;
  }
 }
```

and now my method which first looks if the tree is empty otherwise if its not its gonna call the recursive method

```
public int countOdd() {
    if(root == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return countOdd_rek(root);
}
```

and now the method

```
private int countOdd_rek(BinNode bn) {
    int odd, oddRight, oddLeft;
    odd = oddRight = oddLeft = 0;

    if(bn.left != null) {
        if(bn.left.element % 2 != 0) { //add +1 if bn.left is odd
            oddLeft +=1;
        }
        countOdd_rek(bn.left);
    }

    if(bn.right != null) {
        if(bn.right.element % 2 != 0) { //add +1 if bn.right is odd
            oddRight +=1;
        }
        countOdd_rek(bn.right);
    }

    //add +1 if root is also odd
    if(bn.element % 2 != 0)
        odd = 1 + oddLeft + oddRight;

    //add nothing if root isnt odd
    if(bn.element % 2 == 0)
        odd = 0 + oddLeft + oddRight;
    return odd;
}
```

maybe someone could help it would be very nice... thanks

EDIT I SOLVED IT
SOLUTION:

```
private int countOdd_rek(BinNode bn) {
    int odd, oddRight, oddLeft;
    odd = oddRight = oddLeft = 0;

    if(bn.left != null) {
            oddLeft += countOdd_rek(bn.left);
    }

    if(bn.right != null) {
            oddRight += countOdd_rek(bn.right);
    }

    //add +1 if root is also odd
    if(bn.element % 2 != 0)
        odd = 1 + oddLeft + oddRight;

    //add nothing if root isnt odd
    if(bn.element % 2 == 0)
        odd = 0 + oddLeft + oddRight;


    return odd;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you're not actually doing anything with the values of `countOdd_rek(...)`.  Also, you're defining local variables to store the odd counts which will get overridden with each recursive method call.  A cleaner way to do it would be this:

```
public class BinNode {
    public int element;
    public BinNode left, right;


    public BinNode(int e, BinNode l, BinNode r) {
        element = e;
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }

    public BinNode(int e) {
        element = e;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }

    public static int countOdd(BinNode root) {
        return countOdd_rek(root);
    }

    private static int countOdd_rek(BinNode bn) {
        if (bn == null) {
            return 0;
        }


        if (bn.element % 2 != 0) {
            //add +1 if root is also odd
            return 1 + countOdd_rek(bn.left) + countOdd_rek(bn.right);
        } else {
            return countOdd_rek(bn.left) + countOdd_rek(bn.right);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinNode root = new BinNode(1,
                new BinNode(2,
                        new BinNode(4, null, null),
                        new BinNode(5, null, null)),
                new BinNode(3,
                        new BinNode(6, null, null),
                        new BinNode(7, null, null)));

        System.out.println(countOdd(root));
    }
}
```

I added an example for you in the main method, too.

Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT: Just saw that you solved it yourself.  Nice job--I guess you could look at my code as a reference.**

Comment: your code seems easier to understand. thanks for your help

Comment: No problem.  Good luck!